# Gnuplot to plot columns from a file

Tags: plot, gnuplot

```
0   2013-12-12 23:07:32.677738399   0   Supervisor  range(1,100,24) worker

1   2013-12-12 23:07:32.685011201   0   Supervisor  range(101,200,24)   worker

2   2013-12-12 23:07:32.685287503   1   Supervisor  range(201,300,24)   worker
```

Above is my file.It doesn't have any extension. I want to plot column 1 vs column 3. Gnu-plot is just plotting a straight line. Please help. Column 1 is index and column 3 is a binary entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At which value is the straight line? That should get you to the problem: the time data contains a white space, so that the time data is treated as two columns. You need to plot column 4 vs. column 1:

```
plot 'file' using 1:4 with lines
```

But the line is drawn only, if you don't have blank lines between every entry.